# Does the Synlogy RT2600ac contain a S0-Bus and is compatible with V-DSL?

Tags: synology, vdsl

I'm thinking about buying the [Synlogy RT2600ac](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/RT2600ac) but I wanted to know if it supports the following features:

Does it contain a S0-Bus/ [S interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_interface)?

Is it compatible with V-DSL in Germany/ Does it support V-DSL?

Comment: What exactly is a "S0-Bus"?  Impossible to research the term, so you will have to be more specific, in order for me to submit my answer.

Comment: Hi [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound). I mean the "S interface" as you can read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_interface I need this because I don't want to buy a new telephone as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it compatible with V-DSL in Germany/ Does it support V-DSL?

It does support V-DSL, you would still connect it to your router, in order to access the NAS from any client on the network.  The type of internet you have (ADSL, V-DSL, Cable, Fiber, etc) does not matter.

> Does it contain a S0-Bus/ S interface?

No, It does not.

Comment: Ok, good to know. So, I will think about either buy another router or use an adapter for the S0 interface if there is one. Thanks ;)